# Makefile unable to generate tf files inside account specific folder based on input

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

Below is the make file which will take input of ami.template file as input.

The preprocess target runs the preprocess.sh shell script and passes two environment variables REGIONS and ACCOUNTS. The values of these variables are set to the values of the regions and aws_account_alias Makefile variables, respectively.

generating output files with account-specific data based on the ACCOUNTS variable and region-specific data based on the REGIONS variable.

```
export regions=us-east-1 ;
export aws_account_alias=demo-account
```

Makefile

```
default, help::
    @echo "USAGE:"
    @echo "then make all"

all : preprocess

preprocess:
    REGIONS="${regions}" ACCOUNTS="${aws_account_alias}" ./preprocess.sh ami.template
```

ami.template file

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "${REGION}"
  region = "${REGION}"
}

module "ami_${aws_account_alias}_${regions}" {
  count             = contains(var.regions, "${REGION}")
  source            = "./modules/ami/"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.${REGION}
  }
}
```

preprocess.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

for template in $*
do
    BASE_NAME=$(basename "${template}" .tf.template)
    for region in ${REGIONS}
    do
        # shellcheck disable=SC2002
        cat "${template}" | REGION=${region} envsubst > "${BASE_NAME}"."${region}".tf
    done
done
```

i am looking for solution where template and Makefile should be unique and support from root which should have capability to generate tf files inside account specific folder based on input

```
example:
demo-account-1
  ami_demo-account-1_us-east-1
  ami_demo-account-1_us-east-2
demo-account-2
  ami_demo-account-2_eu-east-1
  ami_demo-account-2_ap-south-1
```

Comment: Double the `$` signs in your recipe (`REGIONS="$$regions" ACCOUNTS="$$...`) to escape the first expansion by make before it passes the recipe to the shell. And, by the way, why do you use make to run such a simple shell command without any form of dependency? And are you sure you want a target named `default,` (with a comma)?